# Obter elementos da lista após insert

Tags: python, sql

Tenho uma lista vazia que será alimentada por `inputs`.

No caso, como faço para inserir os dados armazenados nessa lista em um banco (SQL Server)? Tentei dessa forma mas não funcionou.

```
import pyodbc, datetime

server = '90.90.90.90'
database = 'TESTE'
username = 'teste'
senha = 'teste123'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

now = datetime.date.today()

lista = []

v1 = lista.insert(0,input('entre com um numero:' ))
v2 = lista.insert(1,input('entre com o segundo numero:' ))
v3 = lista.insert(2,input('entre com o terceiro numero:'))
v4 = lista.insert(3,'{}'.format(now))

comandoSQL = ('INSERT INTO TESTE_INPUT (VARIAVEL_1, VARIAVEL_2, VARIAVEL_3, 
VARIAVEL_4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (v1,v2,v3,v4))
print(comandoSQL)
cursor.execute(comandoSQL)
cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[O método `insert` retorna `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1516889), então todas as suas variáveis `v1`, `v2`, `v3` e `v4` terão o valor [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) (ou seja, não terão nenhum valor definido).

Se quer acessar os valores da lista individualmente, pode usar os índices: `lista[0]` para pegar o primeiro elemento, `lista[1]` para o segundo, etc. Então ficaria:

```
comandoSQL = ('INSERT INTO TESTE_INPUT (VARIAVEL_1, VARIAVEL_2, VARIAVEL_3, 
VARIAVEL_4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (lista[0], lista[1], lista[2], lista[3]))
```

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas se quer simplesmente adicionar um valor no final da lista, uma outra opção é usar `append`:

```
lista = []

lista.append(input('entre com um numero:' ))
lista.append(input('entre com o segundo numero:' ))
lista.append(input('entre com o terceiro numero:'))
lista.append('{}'.format(now))
```

Desta forma os elementos já são inseridos no final da lista, e você não precisa controlar os índices manualmente. O uso de `insert` seria mais adequado se você quisesse inserir um elemento em uma posição específica, mas no seu caso parece que você só quer adicionar no final da lista. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou tentar e dou o feedback sobre.

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu demais...

Comment: Aproveitando o tópico, sabe como faço para converter um campo datetime no insert?

Comment: @imaestri Aí já é outra pergunta. Mas eu sugiro que antes pesquise no site, pois já existem muitas perguntas sobre conversão de datas. Se você não encontrar nada para seu problema específico, aí vc cria outra pergunta. Não é que eu não queira responder, é que temos que manter o site organizado: uma pergunta por problema específico (de qualquer forma, se vc não encontrar nada e fizer outra pergunta, responderei se possível) :-)

Comment: Beleza! Obrigado..